# How to get just nested bracket in regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm using Java and I would like to implement a code whose output is `PRP I` when the input is `(NP (PRP I))`.
My current implementation is like the following:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\((.?)\\)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(noun_phrase);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

and its output is `NP (PRP I`.

I know that one possibility would be to count the parentheses, but I'm wondering if there is any way to get just the string inside the nested parentheses using `regex`.

Comment: If you only want the innermost level, try `\\(([^()]*)\\)`. Check [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hO4bN7/1).

Comment: Regex in Java is not that grate with nested structures since it doesn't support recursion. Also solution would depend on possible structure of your input. So we would need to know if it can more nested parenthesis like `(a(b(c(d)e)f)g)`. If so what should be result?

Comment: @Pshemo it can deal with a fixed depth of nesting though.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(.*?\\((.*?)\\)\\)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("(NP (PRP I))");
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

You can use following sites to experiment with Regular expressions.

https://regex101.com/r/cE0dM7/1

http://leaverou.github.io/regexplained/

https://www.debuggex.com/r/gfVglXkY1Cw5D6Mb

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another braces around the group. Also, you need to make sure that between the fixed parentheses you don't match the parentheses:

```
    String noun_phrase = "(NP (PRP I))";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\([^(]*\\(([^)]*)\\)[^)]*\\)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(noun_phrase);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

The negated character classes `[^(]` and `[^)]` make sure you don't match parentheses too eagerly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I don't know how deep you can go with your parantheses, I will suggest two possible solutions.

**Solution 1:** Assuming the depth's exactly as in your question.

This regex will work: `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(([^()]*)\\)")`.

**Solution 2:** Assuming the depths arbitrary (but at least the most inner string is surrounded by parantheses).

In this case, you will have to make some more changes. First, your pattern will look like this: `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\(.*)*\\(([^)]*)\\)")`. See the difference? You now have two groups, the first matching on all but the innermost part surrounded by parantheses, the second group is exactly the one you want. That means, in your loop, you have to change `matcher.group(1)` to `matcher.group(2)`. Furthermore, `[^)]` makes sure, you don't have any closing parantheses in your group.